# Does the switching frequency and ON/OFF time duration of LED affect the power consumption of LED?

Tags: power-supply, led, switching, power-consumption, coin-cell

I want to drive the electronics consisting a controller with different peripherals on its I/O pins, one of which is LED, with 3V coin cell battery supply.

I want to determine if its switching frequency and ON-OFF time of LED is varied, will that affect its power consumption.

Comment: If it's off for 10 s and on for 1 ms do you think it will use the same power as if it's on for 10 s and off for 1 ms?

Comment: Definitely not. Power consumed, when LED is ON and when OFF, will change. But, is there any correlation between switching frequency and power consumption for LED?

Answer (score 1):

The LED power consumption is based on duty cycle (percentage of time on.) An LED circuit that draws 20 mA at steady DC voltage will draw 10 mA at 50% duty cycle.
The switching frequency would have no effect, looking at just the LED and ignoring the control circuit parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If the speed of switching on and off (frequency) is high enough, the human eye won’t see the switching. At 50% of light output, the LED is on half the time and off half the time. To dim the light to any given level, you simply change the ratio of time on and time off.PWM, the LEDs are constantly cycling between on and off states.  By sending a PWM signal to an LED, we can control how bright that LED appears to shine. What’s actually going on is that the LED is turning on and off many, many times in a second. For example, if we send a 50% duty cycle PWM signal at 50 Hz to an LED, it will be on for 10ms, then be off for 10ms, then be on for 10ms and so on. You won’t actually see the LED turning on and off, instead, you’ll see that the LED looks much dimmer than when you set the duty cycle to 100%.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But there is no information on the LED switching and power consumption in your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about reverse recovery loss of diodes, which are proportional to switching frequency, then I would say they are negligible. The power consumption's main factor is the LED on time.

But if still interested, for reverse recovery losses you can use the following equation:
\$P=Q_{rr}V_rf_{sw} \$

Answer (score -1):

Yes power consumption of LED depends on the switching frequency.This is achieved using pulse width modulation. 
The led will be on for some time and off for some time. The led will glow dimmer but the switching itself will not be noticeable. Since it will be off for some time it will definitely save some power. 
However your project just not be abt glowing an LED and the power saved using this PWM method might be negligible and also u might be using up a analog output pin.

Comment: _"Yes power consumption of LED depends on the switching frequency"_ No, it doesn't.